# How LeaveOneOut validation works in GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, grid-search

Suppose, I use LeaveOneOut cross-validation in GridSearchCV. For example:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut    

clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=LeaveOneOut())
```

Here's **the question**: Does GridSearchCV *(1)* test each model with the same hyperparameters on *one* sample only, or *(2)* it creates *n models* (for all *n number* of samples in dataset) with the same hyperparameters and tests each model on one left out sample and than calculates the average score for a model with the same hyperparameters?

The second option seems like the right one, because that is the reason to use LeaveOneOut validation to be able to check your model on all dataset, and to use as much training data as possible, and that's why it's called the costly one, but I doubt GridSearchCV does that.

Comment: Yes the 2nd option is right, but currently GridSearchCV only works as you described in option 1.

Comment: See this question : [Scikit-learn: scoring in GridSearchCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572191/scikit-learn-scoring-in-gridsearchcv)